# Attempt to read property 'avatar' null when register with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8 and have an error,

If I register a user using Laravel it says:

`Attempt to read property "avatar" on null` in views at user index and another one did work properly...

and if login using Laravel from creating the user in admin pages, it says:
`These credentials do not match our records.`

**UsersController.php:**

```
    public function index() {
        return view ('admin.users.index', ['users'=>User::all()]);        
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        //
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt('password')
        ]);

        $profile = Profile::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'avatar' => 'uploads/avatars/1.png'
        ]);

        session()->flash('success', 'User berhasil ditambah');
        return redirect()->route('users');
    }
```

I have using `<img src="{{asset(auth()->user()->profile->avatar)}}`
or `<img src="{{asset($user->profile->avatar)}}`  in the views and didn't work too.

**This is user table:**

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->boolean('admin')->default(0);
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**This profile table:**

```
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->text('about')->nullable();
        $table->string('facebook')->nullable();
        $table->string('youtube')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**User Model**

```
    public function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
```

**Profile Model**

```
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error

> Attempt to read property "avatar" on null

indicates that there are some users with no profile and that is why `$user->profile` returns null so you can make it optional using if condition like this:

```
{{$user->profile !== null ? asset($user->profile->avatar) : asset('path-to-default-image')}}
```

Comment: Finally it works... thanks for your answer :)... but when i create a user in admin user page and login with this user, an error occured: ``These credentials do not match our records``... is it from relationship beetween User and Profile?

Comment: Nevermind, I have solved this problem, the problem is in password... i use this: ``'password' => Hash::make($request->password)`` in UsersController instead of ``'password' => bcrypt('password')``